# Converting dataframe to long format based on unique pieces of information stored in current variable names (separated by "_") using R

Tags: sql, r, dplyr

I'm looking for a way to pull out pieces of information from existing variable names, create new variables to store that extracted information, and convert the data frame to long format based on the newly defined variables.  Dealing with psychology treatment survey responses.

Using R or SQL.

Information contained in the exiting variable names:

episode = each time individual participates in program is an episode
subject = the individual filling out the survey (can be participant, mother, father, etc.)
type = the name of the current survey (note: some surveys have additional identifying information separated by "_")
instance = number of days since admission or discharge
description = question number or other information unique to that column

Currently, the each piece of information is separated by "_".
Here is the format: **episode_subject_type_instance_description**

```
## Have data currently in this format, but with almost 5000 variables  

tibble(case_name = c("Joe", "Mary", "Jane"),
       episode1_student_survey1_day0_Q1 = c(1, 2, 3),
       episode1_student_survey1_day0_Q2 = c("A", "B", "C"))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  case_name episode1_student_survey1_day0_Q1 episode1_student_survey1_day0_Q2
  <chr>                                <dbl> <chr>                           
1 Joe                                      1 A                               
2 Mary                                     2 B                               
3 Jane                                     3 C                               

## Want to transform to long like this:  

tibble(case_name = c("Joe", "Joe", "Mary", "Mary", "Jane", "Jane"),
       episode = "episode1",
       subject = "student",
       type = "survey1",
       instance = "day0",
       description = c("Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2"),
       value = c(1, 2, 3, "A", "B", "C"))
# A tibble: 6 x 7
  case_name episode  subject type    instance description value
  <chr>     <chr>    <chr>   <chr>   <chr>    <chr>       <chr>
1 Joe       episode1 student survey1 day0     Q1          1    
2 Joe       episode1 student survey1 day0     Q1          2    
3 Mary      episode1 student survey1 day0     Q1          3    
4 Mary      episode1 student survey1 day0     Q2          A    
5 Jane      episode1 student survey1 day0     Q2          B    
6 Jane      episode1 student survey1 day0     Q2          C
```

I'm assuming there is some way to pull each piece of information out at a time but not sure how to go about this.

Thanks for any and all help!!

Comment: I think your expected output 'description' and 'value' should be matching with the 'case_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `R`, convert the column types to `character` other than the 'case_name', then reshape to 'long' format with `pivot_longer` and `separate` the `name` column

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
nm1 <- c("episode", "subject", "type", "instance", "description")
df1 %>%
     mutate(across(-case_name, as.character)) %>%
     pivot_longer(cols = -case_name) %>% 
     separate(name, into = nm1)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 7
  case_name episode  subject type    instance description value
  <chr>     <chr>    <chr>   <chr>   <chr>    <chr>       <chr>
1 Joe       episode1 student survey1 day0     Q1          1    
2 Joe       episode1 student survey1 day0     Q2          A    
3 Mary      episode1 student survey1 day0     Q1          2    
4 Mary      episode1 student survey1 day0     Q2          B    
5 Jane      episode1 student survey1 day0     Q1          3    
6 Jane      episode1 student survey1 day0     Q2          C
```

#### data

```
df1 <- tibble(case_name = c("Joe", "Mary", "Jane"),
       episode1_student_survey1_day0_Q1 = c(1, 2, 3),
       episode1_student_survey1_day0_Q2 = c("A", "B", "C"))
```

Comment: Nice solution with `separate()`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which uses `melt()` to reshape from wide to long format and the new `measure()` function to split the column names:

```
library(data.table) # development version 1.14.1 used
melt(setDT(df1), measure.vars = measure(episode, subject, type, instance, description,
     sep = "_"))
```

> ```
>    case_name  episode subject    type instance description value
> 1:       Joe episode1 student survey1     day0          Q1     1
> 2:      Mary episode1 student survey1     day0          Q1     2
> 3:      Jane episode1 student survey1     day0          Q1     3
> 4:       Joe episode1 student survey1     day0          Q2     A
> 5:      Mary episode1 student survey1     day0          Q2     B
> 6:      Jane episode1 student survey1     day0          Q2     C
> ```